# Is it possible to prevent circular imports in SQLAlchemy and still have models in different files?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm new to SQLAlchemy and I'm trying to build models in different files. My model looks like this :

```py
from typing import List, Optional
from uuid import UUID, uuid4
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from database.database import Base


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    password: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)

    bets: Mapped[List["Bet"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")
    scores: Mapped[List["Score"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")
```

When I try to make a request on my API, I get the following error :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't 
proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'Mapper[User(user)]'.
Original exception was: When initializing mapper Mapper[User(user)], expression 'Bet' 
failed to locate a name ('Bet'). If this is a class name, consider adding this 
relationship() to the <class 'models.User.User'> class after both dependent classes have 
been defined.
```

So then I tried to update my model the following way :

```py
from typing import List, Optional
from uuid import UUID, uuid4
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from database.database import Base
from models.Bet import Bet
from models.Score import Score


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    password: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    discord: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(unique=True, index=True)
    points: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(nullable=False, default=0)

    bets: Mapped[List[Bet]] = relationship(back_populates="user")
    scores: Mapped[List[Score]] = relationship(back_populates="user")
```

But then I have a **circular error** issue :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Bet' from partially initialized module 'models.Bet'
(most likely due to a circular import)
```

I'd welcome some help to understand what I'm missing and what are the good practices to work around that issue.

Here's the structure of my project :

```
├── models
│   ├── Bet.py
│   ├── Race.py
│   ├── Result.py
│   ├── Rider.py
│   ├── Score.py
│   ├── Stage.py
│   ├── Team.py
│   ├── User.py
│   ├── __init__.py
```

`Bet.py` imports `User.py` but `User.py` needs to import `Bet.py` as well. Here's how Bet.py looks like :

```py
from typing import Optional
from uuid import UUID, uuid4
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, relationship
from database.database import Base
from models.Race import Race
from models.Rider import Rider
from models.Stage import Stage
from models.User import User


class Bet(Base):
    __tablename__ = "bet"

    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    fk_user: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user.id"))
    fk_stage: Mapped[Optional[UUID]] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("stage.id"))
    fk_race: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("race.id"))
    fk_rider: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("rider.id"))

    race: Mapped[Race] = relationship(back_populates="bets")
    rider: Mapped[Rider] = relationship(back_populates="bets")
    stage: Mapped[Stage] = relationship(back_populates="bets")
    user: Mapped[User] = relationship(back_populates="bets")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the file hierarchy of your module, it's hard to tell you about circular imports with a single file.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that I found is to use the `__init__.py` file in my `models` folder and import all the classes in that file. Then, I can simply import `models` in each model file I have :

```py
# models/__init__.py

from models.Bet import Bet
from models.Race import Race
from models.Result import Result
from models.Rider import Rider
from models.Score import Score
from models.Stage import Stage
from models.Team import Team
from models.User import User
```

Then, I have :

```py
# models/User.py

import models
from typing import List, Optional
from uuid import UUID, uuid4
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from database.database import Base


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    password: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    discord: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(unique=True, index=True)
    points: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(nullable=False, default=0)

    bets: Mapped[List["Bet"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")
    scores: Mapped[List["Score"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")
```

I still find it not that clean because I need to import the models folder itself that I do not really use in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Check the examples [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/mypy.html#mapping-relationships)

I think you may need to specify the class in the `relationship`

```
bets: Mapped[List["Bet"]] = relationship("Bet", back_populates="user")
```

If that still gives you the same error as in your first attempt, try using the TYPE_CHECKING block as in the docs to prevent the cyclic import

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from models.Bet import Bet
    from models.Score import Score

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    password: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)

    bets: Mapped[List["Bet"]] = relationship("Bet", back_populates="user")
    scores: Mapped[List["Score"]] = relationship("Score", back_populates="user")
```